# My Update button is not working

Tags: c#, xampp

Below is the save button event handler:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        con.Open();

        if (txtFN.Text != "" && txtMN.Text != "" && txtLN.Text != "" && txtAge.Text != "" && txtReligion.Text != "" && cmbGender.Text != "" && dateTimePicker1.Text != "" && cmbGrade.Text != "" && cmbStrands.Text != "" && txtPlaceBirth.Text != "" && txtHomeAddress.Text != "" && txtNameLastSchool.Text != "" && txtAddressLastSchool.Text != "")
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tbluser set FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, Religion, Gender, BirthDay, Grade, Strand, PlaceBirth, HomeAddress, NameLastSchool, AddressLastSchool) values (@fname, @mname, @Lname, @Age, @Religion, @Gender, @Birthday, @Grade, @Strand, @PlaceBirth, @HomeAddress, @NameLastSchool, @AddressLastSchool", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname", txtMN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", txtLN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", txtReligion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cmbGender.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", dateTimePicker1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", cmbGrade.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Strand", cmbStrands.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlaceBirth", txtPlaceBirth.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAddress", txtHomeAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameLastSchool", txtNameLastSchool.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLastSchool", txtAddressLastSchool.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close(); 
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully"); 
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
        }  
    }
```

But the code is not working the way I intended.
What did I miss?

Comment: Your SQL syntax is not correct. It should be like this... `UPDATE tbluser SET FirstName = @fname, MiddleName = @Mname...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) DML command uses this syntax:

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [assignment_list]
```

or if you want to update existing record(s):

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [assignment_list] WHERE [condition]
```

Hence, the correct syntax should be like this:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tbluser SET FirstName = @fname, MiddleName = @mname, LastName = @Lname, Age = @Age, Religion = @Religion, Gender = @Gender, BirthDay = @Birthday, Grade = @Grade, Strand = @Strand, PlaceBirth = @PlaceBirth, HomeAddress = @HomeAddress, NameLastSchool = @NameLastSchool, AddressLastSchool = @AddressLastSchool WHERE UserId = @UserId", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFN.Text);

// other parameters

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", txtID.Text); // example for assigning record ID
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The presented query looks like an attempt to do `INSERT` query but it will throw exception due to incorrect syntax.

Comment: Please show the exception message in your question body. Is that contains something message like `Fatal error encountered during command execution`?

Comment: hehehe sorry I already fixed the problem. thanks anyways you helped me alot :)

Comment: tetsu how can I make my save button that even the other text box is'nt filled up will be save as long as the specific text box is filled up

Comment: You can use if-condition to check the corresponding textbox content, or make some of them optional (by removing `Required` attribute in the control or something like that).

Comment: can you help me make code for the condition I'm not yet used to c#

Comment: Please ask other code part you want to fix in different question, but try it yourself first. You can ask when the written code is not working properly.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function YourButtonClickEvent() {
        var validation = Page_ClientValidate();
        if (!validation) {
            for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).css("border-color", "red");
                }
            }
        }            
        return val;
    }
</script>

Comment: Sounds like you have different problem than what you're asked here. If you have problem with another code part in your project, I recommend you to ask new follow-up question instead using comment box to show your code.